# My android app crashes when using the onClick callback

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

My app crashes when I click on the submit `Button`, take a look at qf.xml and Math.java as that's where it crashes, the text below is from the `logcat`(from the initialization of the app till it crashes):

```
05-20 12:08:11.671: D/libEGL(22022): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
05-20 12:08:11.686: D/libEGL(22022): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
05-20 12:08:11.694: D/libEGL(22022): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
05-20 12:08:11.694: D/libEGL(22022): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
05-20 12:08:11.866: D/OpenGLRenderer(22022): Enabling debug mode 0
05-20 12:08:16.514: D/OpenGLRenderer(22022): Flushing caches (mode 0)
05-20 12:08:22.335: D/AndroidRuntime(22022): Shutting down VM
05-20 12:08:22.335: W/dalvikvm(22022): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a421f8)
05-20 12:08:22.342: E/AndroidRuntime(22022): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 12:08:22.342: E/AndroidRuntime(22022): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 12:08:22.342: E/AndroidRuntime(22022):    at com.wael.test.Math$1$1.onClick(Math.java:85)
05-20 12:08:22.342: E/AndroidRuntime(22022):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
05-20 12:08:22.342: E/AndroidRuntime(22022):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
05-20 12:08:22.342: E/AndroidRuntime(22022):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-20 12:08:22.342: E/AndroidRuntime(22022):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-20 12:08:22.342: E/AndroidRuntime(22022):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 12:08:22.342: E/AndroidRuntime(22022):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-20 12:08:22.342: E/AndroidRuntime(22022):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 12:08:22.342: E/AndroidRuntime(22022):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 12:08:22.342: E/AndroidRuntime(22022):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-20 12:08:22.342: E/AndroidRuntime(22022):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-20 12:08:22.342: E/AndroidRuntime(22022):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 12:08:23.913: I/Process(22022): Sending signal. PID: 22022 SIG: 9
```

this is the code for Math.java:

```
    package com.wael.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.wael.first.app.R;

public class Math extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.math);
        final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lf);
        final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.qf);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                setContentView(R.layout.qf);
                final Button submit1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.qfButton);
                final EditText ix = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lfET1);
                final EditText ia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lfET2);
                final EditText ib = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lfET3);
                final TextView result = (TextView)                                   findViewById(R.id.tvResultQf);
            // setting EditText input type
            ix.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            ia.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            ib.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            submit1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Boolean TF = true;
                    String sx = String.valueOf(ix);
                    String sa = String.valueOf(ia);
                    String sb = String.valueOf(ib);
                    if (sx.matches("")) {
                        TF = false;
                        Context context =  getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "Enter a value in x";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text,
                                duration);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                    if (sa.matches("")) {
                        TF = false;
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "Enter a value in a";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text,
                                duration);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                    if (sb.matches("")) {
                        TF = false;
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "Enter a value in b";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text,
                                duration);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                    if (TF == true) {
                        double x = Double.parseDouble(ix.getText()
                                .toString());
                        double a = Double.parseDouble(ia.getText()
                                .toString());
                        double b = Double.parseDouble(ib.getText()
                                .toString());
                        double y = a * x + b;
                        String sy = String.valueOf(y);
                        result.setText(sy);
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            setContentView(R.layout.qf);
            final Button submit2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.qfButton);
            final EditText ix = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qfET1);
            final EditText ia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qfET2);
            final EditText ib = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qfET3);
            final EditText ic = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qfET4);
            final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResultLf);
            // setting EditText input type
            ix.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            ia.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            ib.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            ic.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

            submit2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Boolean TF = true;
                    String sx = String.valueOf(ix);
                    String sa = String.valueOf(ia);
                    String sb = String.valueOf(ib);
                    String sc = String.valueOf(ic);
                    if (sx.matches("")) {
                        TF = false;
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "Enter a value in x";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text,
                                duration);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                    if (sa.matches("")) {
                        TF = false;
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "Enter a value in a";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text,
                                duration);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                    if (sb.matches("")) {
                        TF = false;
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "Enter a value in b";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text,
                                duration);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                    if (sc.matches("")) {
                        TF = false;
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "Enter a value in c";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text,
                                duration);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                    if (TF == true) {
                        double x = Double.parseDouble(ix.getText()
                                .toString());
                        double a = Double.parseDouble(ia.getText()
                                .toString());
                        double b = Double.parseDouble(ib.getText()
                                .toString());
                        double c = Double.parseDouble(ic.getText()
                                .toString());
                        double y=a*(x*x)+b*x+c;
                        String sy = String.valueOf(y);
                        result.setText(sy);
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    });
}
```

}

this is the code for qf.xml (the layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lf"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/enter_all"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FF0000" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/x"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/lfET1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:digits="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/x"
    android:inputType="number" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/a"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/lfET2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:digits="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/b"
    android:inputType="number" >
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/b"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/lfET3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:digits="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/a"
    android:inputType="number" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/qfButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/sub" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/y"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvResultLf"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add the code for the submit's Button `onClick` method and point which is the line 85.

Answer (score 2):

A `NullPointerException` means you tried to access something that hasn't yet been initialized. For example, if you do something like this:

```
Button myButton = null;
myButton.setText("some text");
```

It's syntactically correct, but `myButton` doesn't refer to nothing on the UI yet so trying to change the property of an uninitialized object, will crash your app. Since I can't see your code yet, this is a mere example of what can cause that exception.

From the docs about the `NullPointerException`

> Thrown when a program tries to access a field or method of an object or an element of an array when there is no instance or array to use, that is **if the object or array points to null**. It also occurs in some other, less obvious circumstances, like a throw e statement where the Throwable reference is null.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit :**
In the `OnClickListener` for the first `Button`  *button1* you search for a `TextView` (the *result*)with the id `tvResultQf` but you don't have one in your `R.layout.qf` layout(you have one with the id `tvResultLf`, maybe a typo?) and when you try to use it to set the text(`result.setText(sy);`) it it will throw the `NullPointerException`.

Also in the `OnCLickListener` for the `Button` *button2* you search for an `EditText` with the id `qfET4` but you don't have one in your `R.layout.qf` layout so when you'll try to set the inputType(`ic.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);`
) it will throw a `NullPointerException` again.

There may be other errors this was just at a quick look.

---

You didn't point out which is the line `85`(that throws the exception) but I guess your `TextView` *result* is `null` when you try to set the text on it on the line:

```
result.setText(sy);// the last line in your code
```

If this is line `85` then check the layout `R.layout.qf` and see if have an `TextView` with the id `tvResultLf`. If you have it then also try to clean the project by going to the menu `Project` -> `Clean`.

If this doesn't work post the layout for the `R.layout.qf` file.